# Fast generating sequences with conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence

I'm looking for all combinations of numeric sequences in the form [a, b, c], where a, b, c can take values from the set (0,1,2) and satisfy the condition that each next element is greater or equal than he previous element. Of course I can do it in an animal way like:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(range(0,3), repeat=3):
    if i[0]<=i[1] and i[1]<=i[2]:
        print (i)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2)
```

However, I would like to do it smarter than a monkey, because I will actually be working on larger sequences. How can it be done better while maintaining the step-by-step combinations generation structure?

Comment: @Grismar That doesn't produce what OP wants at all. It completely ignores the condition OP was asking about. On top of that... They are already using product!!

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the `combinations_with_replacement()` function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use another function from itertools to do the job:

```
import itertools

t = [0,1,2]
comb = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(t, 3)

for c in comb:
    print(c)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for :) Thanks